# dockerfile setup for php connecting to Oracle

Tags: php, linux, oracle, docker

I have problem setting up the php connecting to Oracle databases, the following message is encountered:

```
Step 4/7 : ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip /opt/oracle
ERROR: Service 'php-apache' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder164874438/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip: no such file or directory
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
```

## ORACLE oci

```
RUN mkdir /opt/oracle \
    && cd /opt/oracle
ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip /opt/oracle
ADD instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip /opt/oracle
```

## Install Oracle Instant Client

```
RUN  unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntshcore.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntshcore.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libocci.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libocci.so \
    && rm -rf /opt/oracle/*.zip
```

## Install Oracle extensions

```
RUN echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/' | pecl install oci8 \ 
      && docker-php-ext-enable \
               oci8 \ 
       && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1,12.1 \
       && docker-php-ext-install \
               pdo_oci
```

Comment: How the docker image is built? Clearly you are missing `instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip` file. How this file is supposed to appear in the docker build directory? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Answer (score 1):

Your error sounds like something simple with paths or not having the zip file where you think it is.

I suggest you look at Oracle's sample Dockerfiles for PHP: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers e.g. this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers/oraclelinux7/php/7.4-apache-oracledb/Dockerfile).

Also check out [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1), which shows Instant Client.

Do you really need to use Instant Client 12.1?  Oracle Instant Client 19c can connect to Oracle DB 11.2 or later and is easier to get (it doesn't need a click through to download).

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers/oraclelinux7/php/7.4-cli/Dockerfile#L5
Does the above link include the php image ? If yes, where can I put the port mapping and volumne mapping for the php application ?

Comment: Currently, I create a lamp-server folder and includes the following subfolders
html - my php programs

oracle - Dockerfile (contain the above link)

php-apache - Dockerfile
version: '3.7'
services:
        php-apache:
                build:
                        context: ./php-apache
                ports:
                        - 8080:80
                volumes:
                        - ./html:/var/www/html    
                restart: always
        oracle:
                build:
                        context: ./oracle
                restart: always